# How can I make the generated numbers never to be the same?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a beginner in programming and I have been trying to make my 3 random generated numbers and the answer never to be the same, but no matter how I tried I didn't get the result that I wanted. I would be very thankful if someone would put me on the right path :)

This is a piece of code for the first randomly generated number, the other two are exactly the same.

```
//Random number 1
{
    btnAns1.label = "" + random1;
    if(mathOperationL1 == 1)
    {
        random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 24) + 1;
        do
        {
            random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 24) + 1;
        }
        while((random1 > 24) && (random1 === answerL1) && (random1 === random2) && (random1 === random3));
        btnAns1.label = "" + random1;
    }
    else if (mathOperationL1 == 2)
    {
        random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 11) + 1;
        do
        {
            random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 11) + 1;
        }
        while((random1 > 11) && (random1 === answerL1) && (random1 === random2) && (random1 === random3));
        btnAns1.label = "" + random1;
    }
    else if (mathOperationL1 == 3)
    {
        random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 144) + 1;
        do
        {
            random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 144) + 1;
        }
        while((random1 > 144) && (random1 === answerL1) && (random1 === random2) && (random1 === random3));
        btnAns1.label = "" + random1;
    }
    else if (mathOperationL1 == 4)
    {
        random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 12) + 1;
        do
        {
            random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 12) + 1;
        }
        while((random1 > 12) && (random1 === answerL1) && (random1 === random2) && (random1 === random3));
        btnAns1.label = "" + random1;
    }
}
```

There are no errors in the code and everything else is working perfectly.It is just the line of code that is supposed to make the numbers never to be the same just doesn't work and after running the code for few times I eventually get numbers that are the same. `while((random1 > 24) && (random1 === answerL1) && (random1 === random2) && (random1 === random3));`

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while((random1 > 24) || (random1 === answerL1) || (random1 === random2) || (random1 === random3));`

The `&&` operator insists that *all* the tests are true if it is to run again. The `||` is the logical OR, so *any* combination tested will cause the loop to run again.

Edit: I should also say, there seems to be alot of duplicated effort in this code.. perhaps once you are comfortable with your operator's behaviour you will be able to simplify the flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! That saved me a lot of time, the code is working now :)

Answer (score 3):

Your condition **while((random1 > 24)...** is always **false** because you generate numbers like 1 to 24 and they **NEVER** exceed 24.

Lets do it algorithmically.

```
var aList:Array = new Array;

// Put the user's input here. Don't forget that
// TextField.text contains String value rather than int.
aList[0] = 5;

// Each line adds a random element different from
// the elements that are already in the Array.
aList[1] = smartRandom(1, 10, aList);
aList[2] = smartRandom(4, 15, aList);
aList[3] = smartRandom(9, 20, aList);

// Let's see what we get this time.
trace(aList);

// Generates a random int from "min" to "max" inclusive,
// while avoiding all the numbers from the "avoid" Array.
// Note that it doesn't actually checks if it is possible
// to do so, thus smartRandom(1, 1, [1]) will result in the
// infinite loop because conditions will never be satisfied.
function smartRandom(min:int, max:int, avoid:Array):int
{
    var result:int;

    do
    {
        result = min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
    }
    // The Array.indexOf(...) method returns -1 if the argument
    // is not on the given Array or it returns a 0-based
    // index of the element that is equal to the given argument.
    while (avoid.indexOf(result) > -1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment and thanks a lot for telling me about arrays. I'm just starting to learn to programme and that is very worthwhile information for me :)

Comment: @AndreyGrigorashenko I've added some more explanation comments, enjoy.